# Kotlin Singleton leaking memory detected by Leak Canary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin, leakcanary

I'm using this pattern to create a singleton to help me with my firebase operations but unfortunately, it is leaking memory, here is my code.

```
class FirebaseDataSource(private val db: FirebaseFirestore,
                     private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
                     private val firebaseFunctions: FirebaseFunctions,
                     private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage,
                     private val firebaseInstanceId: FirebaseInstanceId) {
companion object {

    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: FirebaseDataSource? = null


    fun getInstance(db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(),
                    firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(),
                    firebaseFunctions: FirebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance(),
                    firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(),
                    firebaseInstanceId: FirebaseInstanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()
    ): FirebaseDataSource =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE
                        ?: FirebaseDataSource(db, firebaseAuth, firebaseFunctions, firebaseStorage, firebaseInstanceId).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }

    fun clearInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null
    }
}
}
```

and I use it in my activity like this

```
private val firebaseDataSource = FirebaseDataSource.getInstance()
```

can help me with a way to fix my memory leak or even a better design for my FirebaseDataSource

Comment: you never assign to `INSTANCE`. You only ever check if it's != null thus you spam create new instances

Comment: @Abdelrhman what leads you to believe you're leaking memory?

Comment: I do assign `INSTANCE` in the `.also { INSTANCE = it }`

Comment: arf, ok, that's well hidden but should work fine, so ignore my comment. However, are you using `clearInstance`?

Comment: LeakCanary is showing it and tbh I am not confident about this design so I need your thoughts.

Comment: What does LeakCanary show as the root of your leak? Can you provide that leak trace?

Comment: You can look at it here in this image https://ibb.co/ntp5eU

Comment: From that, it looks like you're setting up some async request in RxJava with a callback in SplashActivity, and not cleaning up in onDestroy(). In that case, you're leaking a reference to SplashActivity. I don't think your issue has anything to do with this singleton initialization. Your SplashActivity.onCreate() likely has the problematic code.

Comment: not really I have a disposable reference when I subscribe and I dispose it on onDestroy()

Comment: Well, at least from that trace, it seems like somehow that either isn't being cleaned up properly, or it's a false alarm from LeakCanary.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has top level, thread-safe, singleton objects. Why not try something like this:

```
object FirebaseDataSource {
  private val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
  private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
  private val firebaseFunctions: FirebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
  private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
  private val firebaseInstanceId: FirebaseInstanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()

  fun doStuff() {
    db.doStuff()
  }
}
```

and then use it

```
FirebaseDataSource.doStuff()
```

Comment: yes, that would be great if I don't want to pass parameters to my class, 
but If I want to I don't think I can use Kotlin object